# While LOOP on Python, print input again

Tags: python

```
i=1
for i in range(4):
    i=i+1
    print(i,".number is:")
    a=int(input(":"))
    if a>13:
        print("Try again")
```

Hello I a am beginner,I have a code like that, I want it to input a number < than 13 , if input >13 then ask again. But it print :

```
1 .number is:
: 1
2 .number is:
: 2
3 .number is:
: 3
4 .number is:
: 14
Try again
```

Comment: you want to try and use the while loop

Comment: What? I don't understand. What didn't work, and what do you expect to happen? Please [edit] your question to include these details. See [ask], [tour], [help].

Comment: This seems to do what you describe you want it to do.

Comment: Are you trying to accept a value from the user. If the user value is less than 13, then you want to break. If the value is > 13 then you want to ask again. In other words, you want user to enter only a value between 1 and12. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an else clause.  Your loop doesn't break because you don't explicitly tell it to, and it'll run until you enter a number over 13.

```
i=1
for i in range(4):
    i=i+1
    print(i,".number is:")
    a=int(input(":"))
    if a>13:
        print("Try again")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I am confused about the downvotes, what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: the question is to help them with while loop and make this simpler.

Comment: @JoeFerndz No, the OP says that the output is incorrect! It doesn't say anywhere in the question that they want to make the while loop simpler.